# How to set two different variables from different paths and run them in one script in sh

Tags: bash, shell, variables, path, scripting

Please, I need help to correct this .sh script by using two different variables from two different paths.
Thank you for your help!

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

path1="cd /work/bk1088/b382227/pidata/monpctl75"
path2="cd /work/bk1088/b382227/pidata/monpctl25"

for i in "path1/*.nc" and v in "path2/*.nc"; do

cdo -a sub ${i} ${v} /work/bk1088/b382227/pidata/IQR-75sub25/${i}_iqr.nc

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to match one file in path1 to a corresponding file in path2 (not the cross-product of all path1 files and path2 files).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pidata=/work/bk1088/b382227/pidata
files1=( "$pidata"/monpctl75/*.nc )
files2=( "$pidata"/monpctl25/*.nc )

for idx in "${!files1[@]}"; do
    i=${files1[idx]}
    v=${files2[idx]}

    # strip the path and the extension from $i
    iqr=${i##*/}
    iqr=${iqr%.nc}

    cdo -a sub "$i" "$v" "$pidata/IQR-75sub25/${iqr}_iqr.nc"
done
```

To explain `"${!files[@]}"`, from [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual:

> `${!name[@]}`
> `${!name[*]}`
>
> > If *name* is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in *name*. If *name* is not an array, expands to 0 if *name* is set and null otherwise. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each key expands to a separate word.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want but I tried your suggestion  and it gave this error:Error (cdf__create): 304988pidata/IQR-75sub25//work/bk1088/b382227/pidata/monpctl75/lonlat_tas_Amon_MRI-ESM2-0_piControl_r1i1p1f1_gn_185001-255012_1850-2349.nc_p75.nc_iqr.nc: No such file or directory

Comment: I think the error coming from the ${i} in this output script: "$$pidata/IQR-75sub25/${i}_iqr.nc". I wonder if there is a way to change this ${i} into counter outputs. Cause it includes all path

Comment: Try the edited version. The double $$ was wrong too.

Comment: Also, if there is anything about that code that you don't understand, ask questions. Don't trust code you find on the internet.

Comment: Noted with thanks, just I don't understand very well this code "${!files1[@]}".

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

path1="/work/bk1088/b382227/pidata/monpctl75"
path2="/work/bk1088/b382227/pidata/monpctl25"

for i in "$path1"/*.nc; do
    for v in "$path2"/*.nc; do    
        cdo -a sub "$i" "$v" "/work/bk1088/b382227/pidata/IQR-75sub25/${i}_iqr.nc"
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you Gilles for your reponse. However, it still didnt work and said: 'Open failed on >path1/*.nc<'

Comment: Forgot `$` sigill, fixed

Comment: Yes thank you Gilles, now it works but there is a problem with the outputs when I used this:"${i}" in this "/work/bk1088/b382227/pidata/IQR-75sub25/${i}_iqr.nc" cause it includes all path1. Therefore, I wonder if there is another way to change to outpuTs counter?

Comment: Looks at [Glenn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76105210/465183)